# org.apache.jasper.JasperException:The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar

Tags: java, jsp, exception, jstl

I have a Spring Boot based web-application. It runs well, but when I try to call some page I get

> 2018-02-20 19:00:40.504 ERROR 5156 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [jsp] threw exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/Welcome.jsp (line:
>   [1], column: [1]) The absolute uri:
>   [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either
>   web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:347)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:380)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:481)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.5.jar:9.0.5]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
>   [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
>   [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>   [na:na]   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   [na:na]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

After that its still running but when I call pages I get the same.
Dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Including taglib: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

There is something strange for me in jstl-1.2.jar c.tld:

```
 <description>JSTL 1.1 core library</description>
  <display-name>JSTL core</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>c</short-name>
  <uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>
```

Why jstl-1.1 there?

Comment: Does your application have `web.xml`? If yes, please show us `<web-app>` tag.

Comment: it doesn't. Only pom.xml

Comment: Isn't there another JSTL library in your app's `WEB-INF/lib` or container's lib directory?

Comment: There wasn't, but then I created WEB-INF/lib and put there jstl.jar and it works. But I have another jstl.jar in External libraries. So I have two jstl.jar, but without WEB-INF/lib/jstl.jar it doesn't work. Even when I put jstl.jar from WEB-INF/lib to .m2 repo

Comment: I have the same issue did you get resolved the issue?